# Build a child theme to display a static page as site’s front page in a wordpress multisite environment

Tags: wordpress, multisite

The use case is to show a customized theme with a static page as front page when a new site is created in a multisite installation.
I tried with starter content but it is seems that the feature is not yet supported https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38624

Comment: You can set up one of the sites to be a "master" site with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-cloner/ and then new sites will be its copy. I don't understand your question completely, but seems to me that this should work for you. One downside, the plugin is kind of abandoned. I think it still works good though.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay, I just need a way to setup a "default" site for all sites in a multisite environment. I setup all the customizer options programmatically but it doesn't work as in trac I mentioned in my question. The way you suggest is a simpler way to do it and it is works. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Only downside is the plugin is not updated for a year. I am actually planning to add this feature in my premium plugin. When I do, I will let you know here (maybe you will want to switch to it if the multisite cloner continues to not be updated and eventually stops working with newer WordPress).